# How to query fields with multiple values in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Working on Azure Cognitive Search with backend as MS SQL table, have some scenarios where need help to define a query.

Sample table structure and data :

[image]

**Scenarios 1 :** Need to define a query which will return data based on category.
I have tied query using *search.ismatch* but its uses prefix search and matches other categories as well with similar kind of values i.e. "Embedded" and "Embedded Vision"

> $filter=Region eq  'AA' and search.ismatch('Embedded*','Category')

```
https://{AZ_RESOURCE_NAME}.search.windows.net/indexes/{INDEX_NAME}/docs?api-version=2020-06-30-Preview&$count=true&$filter=Region eq  'AA' and search.ismatch('Embedded*','Category')
```

And it will response with below result, where it include "Embedded" and "Embedded Vision" both categories.

[image]

But my expectation is to fetch data only if it match "Embedded" category, as highlighted below

[image]

**Scenario 2:** For the above Scenario 1, Need little enhancement to find records with multiple category

For example if I pass multiple categories (i.e. "Embedded" , "Automation") need below highlighted output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve above mention problem used a below SQL function which will convert category to a json string array supported by  `Collection(Edm.String)` data type in Azure Search.

**Sql Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCategoryAsArray
(
    @ID VARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SET @result = REPLACE( 
        STUFF(
            (SELECT 
                ','''+ TRIM(Value) + ''''
             FROM dbo.TABLEA p
                CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (Category, ';')
             WHERE p.ID = @ID
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,''),'&amp;','&')
    RETURN '[' + @result + ']'
END
GO
```

**View to use function and return desired data**

```
CREATE View dbo.TABLEA_VIEW AS
select 
       id
      ,dbo. GetCategoryAsArray(id) as CategoryArr
      ,type
      ,region
      ,Category
from dbo.TABLEA
```

Defined a new Azure Search Index using above SQL View as data source and during Index column mapping defined `CategoryArr` column as `Collection(Edm.String)` data type

Query to use to achieve expected output from Azure Search

```
$filter=Region eq  'AA' and CategoryArr/any(c: search.in(c, 'Embedded, Automation'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to use a different analyzer which will break the tokens on every ';' just for the category field rather than 'whitespaces'.

Answer (score 1):

You should first ensure your Category data is populated as a Collection(Edm.String) in the index. See [Supported Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types#edm-data-types-used-in-azure-cognitive-search-indexes-and-documents) in the official documentation. Each of your semicolon-separated values should be separate values in the collection, in a property called *Category* (or similar).

You can then filter by string values in the collection. See [rules for filtering string collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-troubleshoot-collection-filters#bkmk_strings). Assuming that your index contains a string collection field called *Category*, you can filter by categories containing *Embedded* like this:

```
Category/any(c: c eq 'Embedded')
```

You can filter by multiple values like this:

```
Category/any(c: search.in(c, 'Embedded, Automation'))
```

Start with clean data in your index using proper types for the data you have. This allows you to implement proper facets and you can utilize the syntax made specifically for this. Trying to work around this with wildcards is a hack that should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you @Dan, this is really helpful and I am able to solve my problem